# How to delete/destroy comments with Opinio gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I am using the [Opinio gem](https://github.com/Draiken/opinio) for handling comments on one of my models. I am also using cancan for authroization.

I can add comments, no problems, but I can not figure out how to delete the comments. I simply get a text string back saying "unauthorized". That's it.

Here is my render code:

```
<!-- _comment.html.erb (generated by Opinio) -->
<% reply = defined?(reply) ? reply : false %>
<dt id="comment_<%= comment.id %>"><%= link_to comment.owner.name, comment.owner %></dt>
<dd class="well">
  <%= simple_format(comment.body) %>
  <% if can? :delete, comment%>
    <%= link_to t('opinio.actions.delete'), comment_path(comment), :method => :delete%>
  <% end %>
  <% if Opinio.accept_replies && !reply %>
    <span><%= link_to t('opinio.actions.reply'), reply_comment_path(comment), :remote => true %></span>
    <ul id="comment_<%= comment.id %>_replies" class="replies">
      <%= render :partial => "opinio/comments/comment", :collection => comment.comments, :locals => {:reply => true} %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</dd>
```

The strange thing is that my initial `if can? :delete, comment` works, so I do get the delete link up. I removed a `:remote => true` here, so that I could see what is actually going on.

This is my ability.rb:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
      can :access, :rails_admin   # grant access to rails_admin
      can :dashboard
    else
      can :read, :all
      can :delete, Comment, :owner_id => user.id
    end
  end
end
```

I have looked in the [source code](https://github.com/Draiken/opinio/blob/master/app/controllers/opinio/comments_controller.rb) of opinio and I find the test that I believe is failing:

```
#In opinio gem: comments_controller.rb
if can_destroy_opinio?(@comment)
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Can you subclass opinio's `comments_controller` and override `can_destroy_opinio`?  If not, can you re-open opinio's `comments_controller` and redefine `can_destroy_opinio` (commonly called a monkey patch)?